# Kernel backports for OpenWRT

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, openwrt

Is it possible to cross-compile backports for OpenWRT? I wanted to make a bin file for OpenWRT with older kernel and after installation cross-compile backports of ath10k. I had many problems but even I am not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: I would suggest that you post what problems you are facing, rather than a very broad question like this. The answer to "Is it possible" could be "NO, it's impossible" or "yes, with this small additional hack". But without knowing the exact problem, it's hard to tell without trying ourselves.

Comment: Of course, in fact Openwrt uses a backport to support wireless (compat-wireless).